# Script src which returns redirect

Tags: javascript, html, amazon-web-services, redirect, amazon-cloudfront

I would like to use static url for my versioned JS bundle. Like

```
https://some-cdn-domain/latest/bundle.js
```

The problem is that it's uploading to Cloudfront and caches if upload occures to same directory. I could invalidate caches but it's not convenient and waiting time is too long anyway.

So, I'm creating some backend which is going to redirect that url to latest bundle version like

```
https://some-other-domain/latest/bundle.js -> https://some-cdn-domain/v123/bundle.js
```

So my question is if I use this redirect URL as src to `<script>` tag on html page, will redirect to the latest version always occure or there're going to be some limitations or caveats.

Sadly, googling didn't give anything